# Django Crispy Forms - Layout Div

Tags: django, forms, helper, django-crispy-forms

I'm creating a crispy form from a DB model.

I'd like to put ALL fields from the model in my div helper... Is there a way to do it so that I don't need to write down every single one of them... like:

```
self.helper.layout = Layout(
   Div('field1', 'field2', 'field3', ...), 
   ...
)
```

I tried

```
Div('*')
```

and things like that but it didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Ron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found something in the doc...

I think its the solution... :)

> render_unmentioned_fields = False
>       By default django-crispy-forms renders the layout specified if it exists strictly, which means it only renders what the layout mentions, unless your form has Meta.fields and Meta.exclude defined, in that case it uses them. If you want to render unmentioned fields in the layout, for example if you are worried about forgetting mentioning them you have to set this property to True. It defaults to False.

Comment: In django-crispy-forms versions 1.7.0 and above, even if Meta.fields are defined, if you don't set render_unmentioned_fields to True the fields will not be included. I'm not sure if this is a bug or a feature. https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms/issues/848